# Is it possible to perfect forward a template template parameter

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding, template-templates

I know how to perfect forward a parameter. However, I read from different sources (e.g. Effective Modern C++ Item 24 - Scott Meyers) that one can only perfect-forward when you have the exact template name, e.g.:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T&& param) { bar(std::forward<T>(param)); }
```

What I am looking for is if there is a way to perfect forward an template template parameter, e.g.:

```
template<template<int, class TypeT> class Vector, int Size, typename TypeT>
void foo(Vector<Size, TypeT>&& param) { bar(std::forward<Vector<Size, TypeT>>(param)); }
```

When I compile the above, I get an error message: "You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference" (VC12), which suggest to me that the compiler does not recognize the && as a "universal reference" but as an rvalue reference. This perfect fowarding could be useful to me because I can take advantage of the deduced TypeT and Size.

The question: is it possible to perfect forward template template parameters? If so, where is my syntax incorrect?

Thanks!

Comment: No. You need to take `T&&`, and then inspect `std::decay_t<T>` later.

Comment: You may also do 2 overloads, one for r-value, one for l-value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "universal reference" (the standard term is *forwarding reference*) is (by definition) an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter, i.e., `T&&`.

`Vector<Size, TypeT>&&` is an rvalue reference, not a forwarding reference.

If you want to get the value of the template arguments, write a trait:

```
template<class> struct vector_traits;

template<template<int, class TypeT> class Vector, int Size, typename TypeT>
struct vector_traits<Vector<Size, TypeT>>{
    static constexpr int size = Size;
    using value_type = TypeT;
};
```

And inspect `std::decay_t<T>`:

```
template<class T>
void foo(T&& t) {
    using TypeT = typename vector_traits<std::decay_t<T>>::value_type;
    // use TypeT.
}
```

You can also move it to a default template argument, which makes `foo` SFINAE-friendly (it's removed from the overload set if `std::decay_t<T>` isn't a "vector"):

```
template<class T,
         class TypeT = typename vector_traits<std::decay_t<T>>::value_type>
void foo(T&& t) {
    // use TypeT.
}
```