# How do you capture the elements of a vector with specified variables elegantly?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a function `foo()`, it returns a `vector` with three elements.
I want specify three variables to capture the elements at index `0`, `1`, `2`. Obviously I know the normal code, like

```
auto vec = foo();
a = vec[0]; b = vec[1]; c = vec[2];
```

But I want an elegant format, just like Python, as follows:

```
auto& [a,b,c] = foo();
```

Is there any way to implement it?

Comment: What should the behavior be if there are only two elements in the vector? And what if there are 1000? A vector is meant to be dynamic. If you are certain it's always three elements, return a std::array<...,3> where you can use structured bindings.

Comment: Without knowing what `foo` really returns, my guess is that it returns a vector *by value*. Which means it's a temporary value, which will cease to exist and be destructed immediately. Which means you can't save references to individual elements. That's *one* reason it's not possible.

Comment: But the main problem is that because a vector have an unknown (at compile time) number of elements, it's just not possible to decompose it. The compiler doesn't know how many elements there are. Remember that C++ doesn't have the concept of "null" or "none" values, like Python have.

Comment: XY-Problem? If you need 3 elements, use a data type which has 3 elements. Maybe an array, maybe a tuple.

Comment: Thanks guys, I should write the code like `auto [a,b,c] = foo()` , and `foo()` returns vector values `{1,2,3}`. I just got a solution,  use `tuple`  to replace `vector`, and `tie(a,b,c)=foo()` is good enough.

Comment: @AnnaYin It only needs to be a `std::tuple` if the types can be different for each element. Otherwise `std::array` is simpler. And `auto [a,b,c] = foo();` will just work in both cases, no need for `tie`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`auto [a,b,c] = foo();` ([structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)) would be possible for a tuple-like type such as `std::tuple` or `std::array`, but it's not possible for `std::vector`.
However, you can use structured bindings syntax with a slight workaround:

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::array<T, 3> first_three(const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    if (vec.size() < 3) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("vec must contain at least three elements");
    }
    return { vec[0], vec[1], vec[2] };
}

auto [a, b, c] = first_three(foo());
```

That being said, if you're only interested in the first three elements, perhaps `foo()` should return a `std::array<T, 3>` or some other tuple-like type. Perhaps `std::vector<T>` was the wrong type to use in the first place.

#### Note on move semantics

`first_three` only works for copyable types in its current state. You can add an rvalue overload to avoid copying:

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::array<T, 3> first_three(std::vector<T>&& vec) {
    if (vec.size() < 3) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("vec must contain at least three elements");
    }
    return { std::move(vec[0]), std::move(vec[1]), std::move(vec[2]) };
}
```

There are ways to have only one function as well, but it would be quite annoying to implement. For starters, [`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) has no rvalue overloads and you don't have [`std::forward_like`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward_like) in C++17, so forwarding the elements out of the vector is a bit tricky.

Comment: One could mention that in practice the `first_three` function could check the size of `vec` (at runtime) and use default values (default constructed `T`, if possible) or throw an exception, if too small. The last edit implemented the exception :-)

Comment: If needed, one can also make a template parameter out of the number 3 to make the function even more universal. The most complicated thing is the return line in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Let’s say we want structured binding functionality for vectors (or arbitrary other indexable containers) which

0. perfect-forwards the container reference to its `operator [](size_t)`, just in case it has a special implementation for R-values, and
1. works with element references, i.e. one can assign back into the container’s elements using the structured-bound “variables”.

Admittedly, (1) above is a controversial idea. First, an additional level of indirection may reduce performance with simple types, in exchange for a possibly undesired “benefit”. Second, the example below does not work with structured binding’s `auto&` declarations and has the same effect with merely `auto`, which hampers readability.

In summary, we want this `tie_first_n()` magic to work:

```cpp
const std::vector<int> a{0}, b{0, 1}, c{0, 1, 2}, d{0, 1, 2, 3};

auto [a0]{tie_first_n<1>(a)};
auto [b0, b1]{tie_first_n<2>(b)};
auto [c0, c1, c2]{tie_first_n<3>(c)};
auto [d0, d1, d2, d3]{tie_first_n<4>(d)};

std::cout << a0 << '\n'
          << b0 << b1 << '\n'
          << c0 << c1 << c2 << '\n'
          << d0 << d1 << d2 << d3 << '\n';
```

```
0
01
012
0123
```

And we want the structured-bound symbols to “work” as L-value references, too:

```cpp
std::vector<int> a{0}, b{0, 1}, c{0, 1, 2}, d{0, 1, 2, 3};

auto [a0]{tie_first_n<1>(a)};
auto [b0, b1]{tie_first_n<2>(b)};
auto [c0, c1, c2]{tie_first_n<3>(c)};
auto [d0, d1, d2, d3]{tie_first_n<4>(d)};

++a0;
++b0; ++b1;
++c0; ++c1; ++c2;
++d0; ++d1; ++d2; ++d3;

std::cout << a[0] << '\n'
          << b[0] << b[1] << '\n'
          << c[0] << c[1] << c[2] << '\n'
          << d[0] << d[1] << d[2] << d[3] << '\n';
```

```
1
12
123
1234
```

Let’s discuss the *perfect forwarding* requirement (0). The difficulty it brings into the exercise stems from the fact that you [cannot use a `template template` as a universal reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35712762). For example, when unwrapping a container template `C` with element type `T`, a `template<template <typename...> class C, typename T, typename ... A>` won’t make it possible to perfect-forward from a universal reference `C<T, A...>&&`, because the latter is considered an R-value reference. So we need to make `C` a (non-`template`) type argument and inspect it using a separate type trait that unwraps its element type:

```cpp
template <typename...> struct Trait;

template <template <typename...> class C, typename T, typename... A>
struct Trait<const C<T, A...>> { using Type = const T; };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename T, typename... A>
struct Trait<C<T, A...>> { using Type = T; };

template <typename C>
using Element = Trait<std::remove_reference_t<C>>::Type;
```

With the above in place, we can implement `tie_first_n()` now:

```cpp
template <typename C, size_t... I>
auto tie_first_n(C&& container, std::index_sequence<I...>)
    -> std::array<std::reference_wrapper<Element<C>>, sizeof...(I)> {
  return {std::forward<C>(container)[I]...};
}

template <size_t N, typename C>
auto tie_first_n(C&& container)
    -> std::array<std::reference_wrapper<Element<C>>, N> {
  return tie_first_n(std::forward<C>(container), std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

Notice the `reference_wrapper`, which (as mentioned above) is a source of confusion.

- In the first (`const`) example, `auto`, `const auto` and `const auto&` will exhibit the same behavior. (Not the same inner workings under the hood, but the same *observed behavior*.)
- In the second (non-`const`) example, again, `auto`, `const auto` and `const auto&` all yield the same, non-`const` (!) behavior. (It is a `reference_wrapper` we are making (non-)`const`, not the referenced value.)
- In both examples, `auto&` *will not compile* at all, which may surprise readers unaware of the `reference_wrapper` trick.

#### **[Here’s the whole example in Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/P3KMfsMrW)**

Comment: I wouldn't rely on `template <typename...>` parameters in `Trait` because containers aren't required to have such template parameters. For example, this wouldn't work for `std::array` since it has an NTTP. Instead, I would obtain the element type from the container's iterators or from `value_type`.

Comment: @JanSchultke Good point. Actually it would fail miserably for `std::map<size_t, Something>`, because it would try to bind to the `size_t` and not the value or the key/value pair… A better solution would probably grab `value_type` for vectors and `mapped_type` for maps… It should try `mapped_type` first and if that doesn’t exist, maybe a SFINAE trick could then make it default to `value_type`.